# Вопрос по массивам и циклам в языке С

Tags: c

разбираюсь с массивами и циклами в С. У меня появились проблемы с инициализацией массива и потом его вывода. Я хочу создать массив с количеством n элементов (то есть размерность массива выбирает пользователь), и потом сделать так, чтобы пользователь ввел значения для массива и потом чтобы программа их вывела. Массив надо сделать вещественного типа. Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "locale.h" 
int main() { 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus"); 
    printf("введи размер массива\n"); 
    int size; 
    scanf_s("%d", &size); 
    double arr[size]; //  инициализирую массив
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  //пользователь вводит элементы массива
    { 
        printf("введи элементы массива\n"); 
        double element; 
        scanf_s("%f", &element); 
 
        arr[i] = element; 
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //тут программа их выводит
        printf("%d элемент массива = %f", i, arr[i]); 
 
 
    }
```

Это список моих ошибок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так, выделяя память для массива динамически. В Visual С размер массива, создаваемого как `type array[size];`, должен быть известен во время компиляции.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "locale.h"
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("введи размер массива\n");
    int size;
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    double *arr = malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    printf("введи элементы массива\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  //пользователь вводит элементы массива
    {
        double element;
        scanf_s("%lf", &element);
        arr[i] = element;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //тут программа их выводит
        printf("%d элемент массива = %f", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно аллоцировать массив как `calloc(size, sizeof(double))`. Я предпочитал `calloc`, так как эта функция обнуляет выделенную память.

Comment: @PakUula Можно. А смысл в лишних действиях? Массив все равно весь считывается...